# Experiment with DNS server resolution DENY policies doesn't work as expected

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, firewall, radius

I am experimenting with DNS server resolution DENY policies, and it doesn't work as expected. Here is the general idea:

1. A test non-domain member with no special settings Windows PC with no special settings/software connects to the network with DHCP enabled.
2. The Windows DHCP server detects that a non-domain member PC has requested a DHCP lease.
3. The Windows DHCP server creates a 'DENY' DNS server query resolution policy to block the non-domain member PC from making DNS queries to internal DNS servers.
4. Internet connections to port 53 are blocked on the external firewall making traditional external DNS queries impossible.

The intended result is that the non-domain member PC is blocked from making DNS queries to both internal and external DNS servers. That is the theory, but in reality it doesn't quite work like this.

What happens is that at first the non-domain member PC cannot access the Internet with a web browser. Then, after about half a minute, the PC suddenly has access. However, name queries to internal DNS servers are still being blocked because nslookup fails on the PC and I can see that DNS queries are being blocked in the server logs.

I speculate that the PC is able to perform name resolution through some other mechanism, possibly DNS tunneling. It bears mentioning that the PC is just a normal PC with default settings and no special software or anything.

Can anybody say with certainty what is happening on the PC side here?

Is there a way to prevent whatever is happening, and totally block name resolution requests from non-domain members? I have access to the Windows DNS and DHCP servers and the firewall.

Comment: so, this "illegal PC" doesn't just magically bypass the DNS block by itself, someone would have to be actively setting up whatever is happening

Comment: I can't help but think blocking outbound traffic based on the MAC address is the way to go

Comment: And the question is? Put in a professional setup. Done. You do a "poor attempt" not following best practices - the result is that this is off topic here.

Comment: I think my casual use of the term NAC confused things. I said 'poor man's NAC' originally as kind of a joke, but somebody edited the question to make it sound like I actually was trying to implement NAC. In reality, what I am doing is more like a casual experiment with DNS server resolution DENY policies and I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: This is a forum for managing IT systems in a business environment, using technologies and practices that are generally acceptable. You may want to try other forums such as Reddit Homelab.

Answer (score 1):

[DNS Over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS)

But seriously, it's 2023. Even the cheapest switches support RADIUS. Don't deploy a jury rigged solution. Configure 802.1x port security.